# Need to compile a program with both C++ and C code using Makefile

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, makefile

I need that a Makefile that someone else previously provided be able to compile .C files with .CPP files. At the time this Makefile was created, we didn’t have any .C files in the project, but that has changed so I modified the Makefile as follows:

```
GPP=g++

CPPSRCS= \
    ./CBDefault.cpp \
    ./testPFDefault.cpp \
    ./PFDefault.cpp \
    ./xapiDebug.cpp \
    ./init.cpp \
    ./tracePriorityManager.c \

CFLAGS= -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -IASB -IALU
-Istub -IIKAN
OBJ_DIR=../build/pxy/obj

OBJS := $(foreach s,$(CPPSRCS:.cpp=.o),$(OBJ_DIR)/$(notdir $s))


PROG=../build/pxy/pxy

$(PROG): $(OBJS) | $(dir $(PROG))
    $(GPP) -o $@ $(OBJS)

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(foreach src,$(CPPSRCS),$(eval $(OBJ_DIR)/$(notdir $(src:.cpp=.o)):
CSRC=$(src)))


$(OBJS): | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(GPP) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $(CSRC)
```

Adding tracePriorityManager.c to the list of CPPSRCS macros.
Compilation results in a long list of error messages with the following content:

```
../build/pxy/obj/tracePriorityManager.c:10:3607: warning: null
character(s) ignored
../build/pxy/obj/tracePriorityManager.c:10:3618: warning: null
character(s) ignored
../build/pxy/obj/tracePriorityManager.c:10: error: stray ?\1? in program
../build/pxy/obj/tracePriorityManager.c:10:3620: warning: null
character(s) ignored
```

Can you suggest a change in the Makefile that would fix the problem?

Comment: Using default rules, a `.c` file is usually compiled using `gcc`. Anyway these are warnings (certainly considerable to fix), not errors.

Comment: Does the name "**CPP**SRCS" ring a bell?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Actually, there **is** an error ...

Comment: @Olaf That one refers to source code not shown :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: As do the warnings.

Comment: @Olaf Sure, of course.

Comment: Doesn't look (just) like a Makefile issue. Looks more like your C source file has some junk characters in it. Perhaps corrupt or inserted by an editor. Have you actually opened the file to see whether it looks as expected? May need to open in hex mode to see some of the characters (e.g. null).

Comment: Without seeing the source of `tracePriorityManager.c` it's hard to be sure, but the symptoms are consistent with feeding UTF-16 (or UCS-2) to a compiler expecting 8-bit input.  Does it look reasonable when you `od -t a <./build/pxy/obj/tracePriorityManager.c`?

Comment: Also, `$OBJS` will contain `./tracePriorityManager.c` - you'll want to make that `./tracePriorityManager.o` so that `$(CC)` is used to compile it (even better, drop the redundant reference to `./`).

Answer (score 0):

You should create a different variable for C sources and compile it with gcc and CFLAGS.
Look at your rule - it transforms *.cpp to *.o,  but doesn't talk about *.c.

Comment: Nice try, but not targeting the real issue, the OP prefers to be left disclosed so far.

Comment: Compiling c with g++ might cause some problems. Fix them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue another way:

I changed the name of the .c file to .cpp and encompassed the source file content in extern "C" { ..file content.. }

Also changed the file name in Makefile from .c to .cpp and resolved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you share the same [ld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29#GNU_linker) and compile flags for both your C++ and C compilation.

```
CSRC = CSOURCE FILES
```

Or just

```
CSRC := $(wildcard *.c)

OBJS += $(foreach s,$(CSRCS:.c=.o),$(OBJ_DIR)/$(notdir $s))
```

As far as I know, g++ can compile GCC files without a problem.

You need to use a wildcard function to actually get the list of files.
My mistake about g++ and C. Only linking is not problematic. You will have to use another set files of OBJC and use `gcc` explicitly in another rule to compile them. Just make sure to sum all object files in OBJ and link against g++.
I really suggest using implicit rules to compile C and C++ and just adding a rule for linking.

Regarding the characters warning. I’m throwing a long shot guess, but might have it anything to with the charset expected from the file? I’m not sure, but I’d try to copy paste the content to a new file on my computer and recompile it.